# React-Select dropdown is not persisting value after reordering(sorting) them by react-sortable-hoc

Tags: react-select, react-sortable-hoc

I am trying to create a list of dropdowns which can be reordered by dragging them. For drag and drop i am using react-sortable-hoc. Here i am attaching a working sample. [Link for sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-field-pymm1?fontsize=14)

To reproduce the issue, Select value in first dropdown by mouse or keyboard. after that drag that element (first dropdown) and drop it at 3rd or 4th position then you observed that dropped dropdown will not persist the value. Selected value displayed at first element. What could be the cause for this? How can i fix it?

Comment: Please mark the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass onSortEnd handler to your srotableContainer as props

```
<List items={this.state.items} onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd}/>;
```

I also suggest you add a key on your Item

```
<Item key={item} data={item} index={index} />
```

Here is the forked sandbox where it is working:
https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-raman-l72xw?fontsize=14

Comment: My bad, i missed it. but after doing this still i am getting same issue. Is it working at your end after selecting and move it ?

Comment: @Eshu yes, try to check the sandbox you posted it works with the handler added

Comment: I added a forked sanbox you can check out

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The problem in my code was i have to pass key in my items. But i am not clearly getting that what should be value of key. It should be data or some unique string. Here i modified your code and pass object insed of plane array of string. Then i am facing the same issue. Please check https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-dewdney-o6wv5

Comment: key can be any unique identifier (not object), however it's not recommended that is something like Math.random() or similar.. https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-fermat-l3d0v here is the fixed version.. please mark the answer @Eshu .. you were passing the key as object which was an issue the object gets converted to string as "[object]" and each of your items had that same identifier which was the issue